# JS: Creating paragraphs in pdfMake columns

Tags: javascript, multiple-columns, pdfmake

How are you supposed to create paragraphs in columns? For some reason my text always comes out as a single line and not a paragraph. I noticed this only happens when using columns.

```
let test = {
    content: [
        'Standard paragraph 1',
        'Standard paragraph 2',
        {
            columnGap: 30,
            alignment: 'justify',
            width: '50%',
            columns: [
                {
                    text: [
                        '1. Aliquam facilisis fringilla ipsum. Phasellus sollicitudin felis eu arcu. Suspendisse potenti.',
                        '2. Aliquam luctus suscipit tellus. In rutrum dignissim nisl.',
                        '3. Hello',
                    ],
                },
                {
                    text: [
                        'Column 2'
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },
    ]
}
pdfMake.createPdf(test).download('file.pdf');
```

Which basically looks like this.

[image: Output pdf]

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Doesn't seem to support margin or padding. They use `\n\n` at the end of text in the playground examples for paragraph effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Array` implementation of `columns` :

*PS: See the [documentation](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake#stack-of-paragraphs) for more examples.*

```
let test = {
  content: [
    'Standard paragraph 1',
    'Standard paragraph 2',
    {
      columnGap: 30,
      alignment: 'justify',
      width: '50%',
      columns: [
        [
          '1. Aliquam facilisis fringilla ipsum. Phasellus sollicitudin felis eu arcu. Suspendisse potenti.',
          '2. Aliquam luctus suscipit tellus. In rutrum dignissim nisl.',
          '3. Hello',
        ],
        'Column 2'
      ]
    },
  ]
}
pdfMake.createPdf(test).download('file.pdf');
```

Comment: I was just about to post my own answer after doing some digging and saw this.